# Is it possible to use MSTest and xUnit in the same Visual Studio solution in separate projects with .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, mstest, xunit

The reason I ask this question is because we started a .NET Core project using MSTest and we have lots of them. But now we want to transition to xUnit without having to change existing unit tests.

If it is possible, how is that done? Currently using project.json file. Can I just add the runner in the project.json? I don't know how to have two runners in project.json.

Comment: Did you tried it? Got any errors? Usually you configure the test runner per project (in project.json), i.e. `"testRunner": "xunit"` in project.json on the root object

Comment: Your edit is ambiguous. In your topic you speak about VS Solution, but in the edit you speak about adding "two runners in project.json" which not in match with the title of the question. Solution can have multiple projects and project.json is **per project** not **per solution**

Comment: Your comment made me realize something. Maybe you can have one test project with xUnit and another project with MSTest. I will edit my question.

Comment: Yes, that's was what I was going to suggest to try out, until you edited your post and added the edit. Multiple runners per project.json is unlikely to work, because per schema you can only have string inside `testrunner` element and no arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't think my test projects even still have a project.json which has a test=runner specified with .NET Core 1.1 - just included nuget packages with the runners and done (I'm using Visual Studio 2017 latest RC).

Should this somehow not be possible for you, why not use a separate project for your new tests?

And finally, are your tests really that hard to update to xUnit? Usually the basic setup is similar enough that some clever find replace does the trick. If not, you should probably consider [using the builder pattern](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/07/15/flexible-and-expressive-unit-tests-with-the-builder-pattern/) for testing. If you're using Resharper you can probably also create some rewrite macro's, etc.

Comment: Replying to "why not use a separate project for your new tests?" The title says, "in separate projects."  It's a good question.